# alignment of global quaternions

Tags: python, transformation, quaternions, coordinate-transformation, imu

I'm working with imu sensor which output orientation quaterinons with reference to a global ENU coordinate system. I want to calculate joint angles between 3 sensors on the lower body (see picture) but I can't find a way to align the sensors to the segments?

[image: Sensors on segment]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "align the sensors to the segments"? Are you trying to find relative alignment between the sensor packages at the start when the person isn't moving? Or ...?

Comment: Hej James 
I want to measure the angle between two body segments where the 2 sensor packages are placed on. However as the axis of the sensor is not aligned with the let say elbow rotation axis I can't simply use the relative orientation between sensors. Instead I need to align the sensors with the body segment during a initial know standing position. However I don't know how to perform the alignment using quaternions.